# MySQL PHP - group results by day/month/year?

Tags: mysql, date, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table (Logs) in which I keep logs of what happens on my server, and I wanted to make a function that would sort the results I got.. To explain better:

My query is.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Logs 
  WHERE username = '$user' 
  ORDER BY cur_timestamp DESC
```

(cur_timestamp is a field in my log table, the timestamp of record insertion)
($user is the username (set previously))

This returns an array as usual of all the records in descending order.
Now what I want to do, is to query the database and get it to only return records that are within a certain day or month, etc, for example, if the user selects a month, I want it to return all the records in only that month.

I have been trying to research what to do, and things seem to be pointing for me to use the `GROUP BY` technique, except this only returns one result. I'm not so sure. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of `cur_timestamp`?

Comment: It's  a date type eg: 2012-05-07 10:35:10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example (Logs in Januar 2012):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Logs 
WHERE username = '$user' 
and cur_timestamp between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-31'
ORDER BY cur_timestamp DESC
```

Only Today:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Logs 
WHERE username = '$user' 
and date(cur_timestamp) = curdate()
ORDER BY cur_timestamp DESC
```

If you want to a specific time from the past til now you can use [DATEADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

Example (Logs of last 30 days):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Logs 
WHERE username = '$user' 
and date(cur_timestamp) >= DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
ORDER BY cur_timestamp DESC
```

Comment: This worked which was great! thanks! Also, is there any way to easily get it to return the 'last' month or only 'today' ?

Comment: Sure, use `cur_timestamp = CURDATE()` :) For more useful functions, see MySQL docs on date and time functions, [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)

Comment: You can use php mktime() function to get last month's timestamp and use this awnser's method to use that timestamp and get results.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I dont think that you need to GROUP BY, but just to add a WHERE to select all Logs in a certain time range

```
SELECT * 
FROM Logs 
WHERE username = '$user'
AND cur_timestamp > '2010-01-01'
AND cur_timestamp < '2012-12-01'
ORDER BY cur_timestamp DESC
```

The only thing you need to do, is to adjust your date ranges. No need for any GROUP BY